# GestureDetector widget cannot detect gesture when Chewie widget is in fullscreen state

Tags: flutter

I display video player using the video_player and chewie packages. I want to detect when the user doubles clicks on the video player. I wrapped the Chewie widget to display the video using the GestureDetector widget. If the video player is not in a fullscreen state, onDoubleTap on the GestureDetector widget can be called, but if the video player is in a fullscreen state, onDoubleTap is not triggered.

I really appreciate if anyone can help me, here is my code:

```
class MediaPlayerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MediaPlayerPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MediaPlayerPage> createState() => _MediaPlayerPageState();
}

class _MediaPlayerPageState extends State<MediaPlayerPage> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoController;
  late ChewieController _chewieController;
  bool _isFullScreen = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
        videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),
      );

      _videoController.addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

      _videoController.setLooping(true);
      _videoController.initialize();

      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoController,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: true,
        autoInitialize: true,
        allowPlaybackSpeedChanging: true,
        allowFullScreen: true,
        aspectRatio: 16/9,
      );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: CommonColors.black50,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 16/9,
              child: GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onDoubleTap: () {
                  print('double_tap_triggered');
                },
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using InkWell instead of GestureDetector.

Comment: @pixel I already did but the problem still remain